# Wordpress sort category dropdown list?

Tags: wordpress, sorting, categories, alphabetical

I am using User-Submitted-Posts Plugin in order to let users submit their images to my wordpress site. Each image is uploaded within a category. The categories are set in the wordpress admin area and are pulled into the submission form using the following code.

My only problem is that this web form pulls the categories through ordered by their category ID not in alphabetical order. Therefore when i ADD a category even if it begins with the letter A, it will appear at the bottom.

Can anyone let me know how to edit the following code to make all categories list in ASC alphabetical order?

```
 <li class="usp_category">
                <label for="user-submitted-category" class="usp_label"><?php _e('Categories'); ?></label>
                <div> 
                    <select class="usp_select" name="user-submitted-category" id="user-submitted-category">

                        <?php foreach($settings['categories'] as $categoryId) { $category = get_category($categoryId); if(!$category) { continue; } ?>
                        <option class="usp_option" value="<?php echo $categoryId;?> "><?php $category = get_category($categoryId); echo htmlentities($category->name); ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </li>
```

Comment: How's $settings['categories'] being populated?  Looks like it'd be easier to sort that when it's populated than at this point.

Comment: Do echo "<pre>"; print_r($settings['categories']); echo "</pre>"; and see the structure first. Variable itself doesn't show how it could be sorted.

Comment: Most likely you need to go to code that creates that $settings array and sort there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't actually try this, and i have no ideea how your plugin works... but the easiest solution that comes to my mind is to do 2 foreach loops. This would be inside your <select></select> :

```
    <?php
    $cats = array();
    // get what you need in an array
    foreach($settings['categories'] as $catid) {
        $cat = get_category($catid);
        if(is_object($cat)) $cats[$catid] = $cat->name; // why htmlentities() ?
    }
    // sort by name
    asort($cats);
    foreach($cats as $catid => $catname)
        echo "<option class=\"usp_option\" value=\"{$catid}\">{$catname}</option>";
    ?>
```

hope it works/helps